# change sqlite limits ad-hoc

Tags: linux, sqlite

default Cenots 7 sqlite3 executable is compiled with limit "sqlite_limit_expr_depth == 1000".

That is causing problems with large queries in our application.

Sqlite is vital component of OS so we cannot just swap it to custom made installation, also future OS upgrades can fail as - again - OS heavily depends on it.

Is there another way to raise mentioned limit?

On db file itself or somehow via app (written in php).
We tried "sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_EXPR_DEPTH,size)" - vide https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html - after connecting to db but error about wrong syntax is returned.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can only lower the limit at runtime, not raise it. Gotta use a version of sqlite compiled with a higher limit. Or fix your queries to not require so much parse tree depth.

Comment: Is setting SQLITE_LIMIT_EXPR_DEPTH to 0 or -1 (disabling) will work?
If yes - how that can be done?